# canvas javascript click no funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

estoy intentando llamar una función al hacer click en un canvas, tengo el siguiente código:

```
    can = document.getElementById("pdf-canvas1");  //get canvas element
    can.addEventListener('click', function_name, false); //register event


    function function_name(e) //handle event
    {           
        document.getElementById("image_modal").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("image_modal").style.display = "block";
        alert('hola');
    }
```

Me muestra la alerta, pero no ejecuta el código style.  También intenté lo mismo pero con jquery, obteniendo el mismo resultado:

```
        $("#pdf-canvas1").click(function(e){
            $('#image_modal').attr('style', 'visibility:visible;');
            $('#image_modal').attr('style', 'display:block;');
            alert('hola');
        })
```

lo que quiero es ejecutar código javascript o jquery (una ventana modal) al hacer click en la imagen canvas.  El canvas:

```
<canvas id="pdf-canvas1" class="img-thumbnail" width="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: que es lo que deseas? debes agregar un ejemplo minimo verificable!

Comment: @Bryro editado, quiero ejecutar código javascript al hacer click en el canvas

Comment: con elemento img funciona, el problema es con canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entendi al 100% tu consulta, pero creo que este ejemplo puede ayudarte, en realidad nada del otro mundo puse un canvas, y con un `addEventListener`, estoy llamando al modal para que se muestre, ya luego tu puedes modificar lo que desees.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("pdf-canvas1");
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

canvas.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
   modal.style.display = "block";
   alert('soy un sayajin');
}, false);

span.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}, false);
```

```css
.img-thumbnail{
   background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ae/bb/2a/aebb2aba5805a17893f72429b5995ee2.jpg");
   background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="pdf-canvas1" class="img-thumbnail" width="100"></canvas>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Este es un modal.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```